# f-string not working in Jupyter not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, f-string

I can run my code in pythontutor and PyCharm and it works.  But, when I try to run my code in Jupyter Notebook for my class, I keep getting a SyntaxError.

I have research the web, and the only thing I could find had to do with a CodeMirror issue.  Not sure what that is.  What am I doing wrong with the f-string?

```
def list_o_matic(blank):
    if new_animal == "":     #check to see if nothing was entered if so then pop last animal  in list
        pop = animal.pop()
        msg_pop = f'{pop} popped from list' # popped for list
        return msg_pop

    else:
        if new_animal in animal:     #check to see if already have animal if yes remove animal from list
            remove = animal.remove(new_animal)
            msg_remove =  f'1 instance of {new_animal} removed from list'
            return msg_remove

        else:
            animal.append(new_animal)      #check to see if animal is not in list if so append list to add animal
            msg_append = f'1 instance of {new_animal} appended to list'
            return msg_append

animal = ['cat','goat','cat']

while True:
    if len(animal) == 0:  #check if list is empty
        print("\nGoodbye!")
        break

    else:         # get animal input
        print("look at all the animals ",animal)
        new_animal = input("enter the name of an animal or quit: ").lower()

        if new_animal == "quit":   # quit entered print msg and leave
            print("\nGoodbye!")
            break

        else:
            print(list_o_matic(new_animal),"\n")
```

File "", line 6
    msg_pop = f'{pop} popped from list' # popped for list
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`msg_pop = f{'pop'}`

to

`msg_pop = f'{pop}'`

Comment: Recheck my code now.  I posted and forgot to put back the correct way that worked with PyCharm. I was playing around with different ways to see if it was different in Jupyter.

Comment: @BrianPrice - With your edit, I can't replicate the problem; seems to work now.

Comment: @BrianPrice - I'm running it in a Jupyter notebook with no problem. Try drastically simplifying your code by deleting from your function everything except the first block and then deleting the `if` loop, and running `print(list_o_matic('cat'))` and see what happens.

Comment: So, I went to Jupyter notebook to see if runs on Jupyter and it does, but our school is using Microsoft Azure Notebook running Jupyter and it gives me the error.  I don't know if it an issue with Microsoft Azure Notebook.  I looked at Azure and it is running Jupyter 5.5 and Python 3.5.4 while Jupyter is running 5.7.8 and Python 3.6.7.  Not sure if that could be the issue.

Comment: @BrianPrice - f-strings are supported from Python 3.6, so that may be the problem. On the other hand, I checked my own Azure Jupyter Notebook and it's running Python 3.6 and the code works....

Comment: After some more research, I found out that in the version our school is running, I need to use .format_map.  Must be an older way string formatted was done in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the f-string is that the brackets must be inside the quotation marks. I.e. instead of `f{'pop'}` it should look like f'{pop}'.

This is because it evaluates pop inside of the string. But it looks like you got it right for all of the other f-strings so must've just been an oversight. Keep it up!

Comment: I actually did the {} inside.  I fixed code to the way it works with PyCharm.  I forgot to fix before posting.